# Is it important that what() does not throw (exception classes)?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, throw

An exercise from C++ Primer asks

> Why is it important that the what function [of exception classes] doesn’t throw?

Since there is no way to check my answer I was hoping to get an opinion. I thought possibly that it is an error (maybe `terminate` would've been called) to throw another exception during a catch clause (other than a rethrow `throw;`) while the current exception object is still being handled. It seems that is not the case though and it is completely okay to throw out of catch clauses:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


    try{
        try{
            throw exception();
        } catch(exception err){ throw exception();}
    } catch(exception err){ cout << "caught"} //compiles and runs fine, outputs "caught"


}
```

So program terminations are not a worry. It seems then, any problem that arises from what() throwing should, at the very least, be rectifiable by the user if they  were so inclined.

Maybe then, the importance might be that while handling an error we do not want further unexpected errors to occur? Throws inside catch clauses are mainly intended for sending the exception object further up the call chain. A user may receive an error from deep in his program and does not want to worry that the error caught has to be associated with its own try block. Or maybe what() having its own throw may also lead to recursive effects (e.g. what() throws an exception, then we catch this exception and call what() but this then throws, and so on) meaning it might become impossible to handle any errors? How drastic can it be for what() to potentially throw?

Comment: If you get an entirely unrelated exception while trying to deal with the first one, you have basically lost all ability to deal with that first one, since the next `catch` will only see the second one.

Comment: what is used to work out what type of exception it is (so you can decide how to handle it). Having that throw is just Not Fair, only Bad Things can happen as a result. Of course BTs can always happen - yr processor catches fire, but the 'what' writer cannot make exceptions part of the normal behavior of her exception

Comment: `std::exception::what()` is noexcept. Is this question supposed to be a mental exercise or ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's nothing unclear - it's just as you described. If `.what()` method of an exception class throws an error, the whole **`catch` effort was wasted**:

```
try {
  someDangerousOperation();
}
catch(std::exception e) {
  // Ooops, instead of false,
  //we get another exception totally unrelated to original error
  someLogClassOrWhatever.save(e.what());
  return false;
}
return true;
```

And Imagine the crazy code if you were expected to deal with `what()`'s exceptions:

```
try {
  someDangerousOperation();
}
catch(std::exception e) {
  // Not very fun
  try {
    someLogClassOrWhatever.save(e.what());
  }
  catch(...) {
    alsoWhatHasFailedThatIsReallyGreat(); 
  }
  return false;
}
```

I think there's nothing more in that, probably the question is so simple it seems there must be some catch hiding in it. I think it's not the case.

Comment: Except, if the code in the `catch` block itself was written with exception safety in mind, they can log the fact that `e.what()` threw an exception instead of returning what it was.  Nothing would be lost.

Comment: That's the second code I posted. And I commented it `Not very fun`. At some point the ammount of `try ... catch` blocks is higher than programmers incentive to prevent all crashes...

Comment: I rather think `std::terminate` would be called before you had to worry about any number of `try ... catch` blocks...

Comment: @TomášZato Yes: you modified your answer since I commented (or at the same time).  Good!

Answer (score 2):

`std::exception::what()` is noexcept. Consequently, if it throws, `std::terminate` is called. Yes, this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Image a very curious coder with a slight tendency towards being a control freak (I know a couple of them myself), he really wants to know what is going wrong in his program and logs all errors with ex.what(). So he codes

```
try {
  code();
}
catch(std::exception &e) {
  std::cout<<e.what()
}
```

He is pretty pleased with the world in general and with himself in particular. But now it crosses his mind, that e.what() could throw an exception as well. So he is codes:

```
try{
    try {
      code();
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
      std::cout<<e.what()
    }
}   
catch(std::exception &e) {
      std::cout<<e.what()
}
```

A minute later he notices, that there is again an uncaught exception possible! Remember, he is a control freak, so he is going to write another try-catch block and than another and another

So you can bet any money, his project will be late - how could you do something like this to my friend? So please make sure `e.what()` doesn't throw:)

I guess it is the reason behind `what` being noexcept.